# Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() gives two values when creating a sidebar and when calling a appscript method from templated html

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I have been using https://github.com/labnol/apps-script-starter as a starter guide to create app script projects for Google Slides.

But I came across an issue related to the context (active user) that the appscript function is called. While calling the method Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() in the onOpen() function I get the correct active account but when I call the same function from a templated HTML I get the default account for that browser. Has anyone faced this issue? A solution will be great.

```
const onOpen = (e) => {
  Logger.log(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
  Logger.log(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail());
  ..
}

const customFunction = () => {
  Logger.log(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
  Logger.log(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail());
  ..
}

const showSidebar = () => {
  const template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('gra-main-v3');
  template.include = include;

  const html = template.evaluate().setTitle('New Sidebar');
  SlidesApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
};
```

gra-main-v3.html

```
<HTML>
...
<script>
    google.script.run.customFunction();
</script>

..
</HTML>
```

I have two google accounts logged in to the same browser emailA@gmail.com (default) and emailB@gmail.com. When using the default account everything works as expected, but while using the second account the custom function called from the templated HTML gives the wrong result.

```
Case 1 When emailA@gmail.com is active:
Results in onOpen = emailA@gmail.com 
Results in customFunction = emailA@gmail.com 

Case 2 When emailB@gmail.com is active:
Results in onOpen = emailB@gmail.com 
Results in customFunction = emailA@gmail.com
```

appscript.json

```
{
"timeZone": "Asia/Calcutta",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [],
    "libraries": []
  },
  "webapp": {
    "access": "ANYONE",
    "executeAs": "USER_ACCESSING"
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
  ]
}
```

Comment: An [mcve] would be good.

Comment: @Cooper Does the edits help ?

Comment: @Cooper this issue is related to the "Exception: Action not allowed" issues. The secondary account is getting this error.

Comment: Avoid being logged in with multiple accounts, you can open separate sessions if needed instead

Comment: @DmitryKostyuk I am working on an addon for a user base. So will be tough to make them understand about the multi account issue for the apps script.

Comment: I feel your pain, but we've [had to live with this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69270374) for quite a while now. You can  star the issue on Google Tracker on the link above to let them know we need a solution.

Comment: This is a multi-acocunt sign-in issue. This is a known issue as @DmitryKostyuk has linked, and the only current workaround is signing out of all accounts aside the one that you wish the script to run as.

Comment: @DmitryKostyuk I came to know about the multi-account issue in google a long time ago but I am confused is this specifically only for the v8 engine? I see that what I want to achieve is working in other google addons.

Comment: What add-ons? How have you tested? Can you be more specific? What makes you think threre is a magic answer that someone knows but Google doesn't? :)

Comment: @DmitryKostyuk In my project, I have to add a background to the slide, so the flow will be adding a new slide to the active presentation and set a background to that slide. Due to this multi-account issue or something else the code to get the active presentation SlidesApp.getActivePresentation() gives out "Exception: Action not allowed" when using from a secondary account. But in https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/pear_deck_for_google_slides_addon/363332900703 the same functionality works for both secondary and default account.

Answer (score 1):

This is a multi-account sign-in issue. Please navigate to the [corresponding issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69270374) on issue tracker and star it, so that Google knows it's important to solve.

Meanwhile a couple of work-arounds have been proposed, which both boil down to alerting the user that there is a multi-account issue:

1. [By Romain Vilard](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/home/announcements/multiple-accounts-issue-with-google-apps-script)
2. [Comment 117](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69270374#comment117) in the tracker.

The idea is to compare the effective user to the current user, or a document owner to the current user, and if they are not the same, then alert the user that they need to sign out out of other accounts.

That's the best we can do for now.

Answer (score -3):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#geteffectiveuser):

`getEffectiveUser()`:

> Gets information about **the user under whose authority** the script is running. If the script is a web app set to "execute as me" (the developer), this returns the developer's user account. If the script is running under an installable trigger, this returns the account of the user who created the trigger. In most other scenarios, this returns the same account as `getActiveUser()`.

So when you call the function from templated HTML, it return the account that own this script (emailA@gmail.com I guess).

You can set `Execute as` to `User accessing the web-app' if necessary (also reffer to add-on). [image: See Example image.]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I have already set it in appscript.json

  "webapp": {
    "access": "ANYONE",
    "executeAs": "USER_ACCESSING"
  },